# Breadcrumbs with structured data not displaying properly

Tags: breadcrumbs

I've looked at a lot of documentation but I can't figure out if the structured data should be placed on all pages?  For example, I have this code on my main home page:

```html
<ol vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="BreadcrumbList">
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
    <a href=".." property="item" typeof="WebPage">Home</a>
    <span property="position" content="1"></span>
    <span property="name" content="Home"></span>
  </li>

  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
    <a href="../p/about" property="item" typeof="WebPage">About</a>
    <span property="position" content="2"></span>
    <span property="name" content="About"></span>
  </li>
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
    <a href="../p/services" property="item" typeof="WebPage">Services</a>
    <span property="position" content="2"></span>
    <span property="name" content="Services"></span>
  </li>
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
    <a href="../p/contact" property="item" typeof="WebPage">Contact</a>
    <span property="position" content="2"></span>
    <span property="name" content="Contact"></span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Although Google now shows all the breadcrumbs like this:

[image: Google search result]

Is it a problem with my relative URLs? Should I not include the meta data for other pages that the user isn't on?